# Benefits of manual lookup over joining in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, performance

Is constructing and using a manual lookup (`ILookup<T>`) approach any faster than using a join with `Join` or `GroupJoin` on a local `IEnumerable<T>` sequence in LINQ?

I read somewhere that the compiler actually translates the inner sequence of `Join` and `GroupJoin` to `ILookup<T>` anyway.

What would `ILookup<T>` benefits of using it on it's own be?

Comment: While the question is interesting, it seems like premature optimization to me. If the code you are writing is performance critical, you should monitor it. If it is fast enough, go on with the next task.

Comment: Some example code would make your question clearer.

Comment: @Stephen - I was trying to figure out the pros and cons of such an approach and if what I stated here that the actual join is translated into a lookup

Comment: @Ian - I'll add some code later to illustrate what I'm trying to say

Comment: To analyse LINQ, I often profile the LINQ-to-SQL calls wil SQL Server profiler. I find out the query time and the query translation for the LINQ code. If it can helps.

Comment: @Philipe - LINQ to SQL is not the subject here, I know that IQueriable<T> get interpreted as expression trees and is translated to SQL at runtime. The subject are IEnumerable<T> i.e. joins on local collections and if they truly utilize ILookup.

Comment: @Philippe - LINQ != Linq to SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. If you're working with objects that are DataContext based, then the join gets translated all the way down into the SQL server via the select statement.  IF its a POCO (or more specifically a Plain Old CLR collection) or something else, then yes, its utilized as ILookup.